# How I make rabbitmq's customer script listening continuously

Tags: php, linux, rabbitmq

I must implement a rabbitmq solution for a web-service.
Well I decided to deploy a simple queue, with a producer and one customer.
My questions are how to make costumer.php listening continuously for request from producer.php? May I append it to my crontab? How do I define a worker process that will work on background?

How can I send SOAP call to the costumer?

Comment: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html

Comment: How to keep customer running to listen for messages and do what ever with them ?

Answer (score 1):

The

```
while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
```

loop is doing the waiting part. It will run forever, calling the $callback function/class as needed.

In the tutorial, you can replace the $callback (which is a function here) by an array containing the instance of a consumer class and the function to call, ie `array($consumer, 'processMessage')`. The function will receive the message as a parameter.

In the tutorial, the receive.php will run indefinitely : you can run it as a daemon (with runit for instance) if you wish.

If you wish to use a SOAP call, it has nothing do to with rabbitmq. You can use both if you wish and they can call the same classes to do the tasks, but you will have to create another layer of code.